# High Charts export-server not rending legend LabelFormatter

Tags: node.js, highcharts, pie-chart

I have the following code for the node.js high-Charts export-server the legend is showing but the label formatted is not applied and the function is not executed also

I have tried the load function also and it is not working, I tried custom HTML and it is now showing also

[image: https://ibb.co/HTQp2xB]

```
let chartDetails = {
    type: "png",
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        title: {
            align: 'left',
            floating: false,
            text: 'Main Title',
            style: {
                fontSize: '24px'
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            align: 'center',
            floating: false,
            text: '<b>300</b><br>Total Issues',
            style: {
                fontSize: '30px'
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '70%',
                shadow: false,
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0,
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormatter: function () {
                console.log("this: is equal to ");
                console.log(this);
                return 'custom word';
            }
        }
        ,
        series: [
            {
                data: [
                    {
                        name: "a",
                        y: 100
                    },
                    {
                        name: "b",
                        y: 20
                    },
                    {
                        name: "c",
                        y: 50
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

};

I expected 'custom word' instead 'a','b','c' is showing

Answer (score 0):

It seems when using `node-export-server` as a module callback functions are not supported. Check this thread on the module github: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/122.

As a workaround, you can use `labelFormat` property instead of `labelFormatter`:

```
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 0,
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormat: "custom word"
  }
```